# Testing for a Power class using JUnit

Tags: java, junit, junit4

Here is the class I am seeking to test:

```
package math;
import java.lang.Math;
public class Power {

public double powerFinder (double x, double y) 
    {

        return Math.pow(5, 4);

    }

}
```

Here is the test:

```
@Test

public double testPower() {

    Power power = new Power();
    assertEquals("Result", 625, power.powerFinder(5, 4), epsilon);
}

}
```

At the moment I'm getting 'the method powerFinder(double) in the type Power is not applicable for the arguments (int,int).  How do I solve this please, so the test will run?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare `powerFinder (double x)`, so you need to pass **one** `double` argument, and not **two** `int`s.

Use:

```
power.powerFinder(5)
```

or change the method to be:
`powerFinder (double x, double y)`

You can also change `double` to `void` in `public double testPower() {`

Your test function doesn't return any value, so you need to declare it as `void` return type.

I think you should read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html)

Comment: I've done that, and am now getting 'this method must return a result of type double' for the test method.  How do I solve this?  Do I need to add an extra return statement?

Answer (score 0):

Change your code to:

```
public double powerFinder (double x, double y); 
{

    return Math.pow(x, y);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the type `double` does not mean `a pair of values`, but a *single piece of a double precision floating point number*. Also, your method doesn't even use that single parameter.

So this:

```
public double powerFinder (double x) 
{
    return Math.pow(5, 4);
}
```

should be rewritten to:

```
public double powerFinder (double x, double y) 
{
    return Math.pow(x, y); // note x and y: those are the arguments of your function
}
```

But this in itself makes no sense, you could just use `Math.pow(x, y)` instead. Of course then your test would make no sense too...

(Similar constructs *could* make sense, to hide implementation details when dealing with an API, and provide an abstraction - but in this case this doesn't seem applicable...)